# Why this JavaScript includes() feature make sense?

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, nan

I'm learning about includes() feature, and I found this code

`[NaN].includes(NaN) //True`

But

`NaN === NaN // False`

Why this is posible?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? You can easily define your own logic for comparing values: `function isSame(a, b) { return isNaN(a) ? isNaN(b) : a === b;}`. And if *you* can do that, the language can do it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using equality `NaN === NaN` and using includes `[NaN].includes(NaN)` are basically asking two different questions:

1. Equality - are this things that have the same name are actually equal?

`NaN` is an amorphic entity, which describes the concept of not being a numeric value, and doesn't actually have a value you can compare. Equality uses the [Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison), and defines that a comparison `x === y` with `NaN` on any side of the equation is always `false`:

> a. If x is NaN, return false.
>   b. If y is NaN, return false.

2. Includes - do I have something with that "name" in the array?

However, to search for a `NaN` in an array, and to keep the to Array#includes signature of passing only one param, and not a callback, we need a way to "name" what we are searching for. To make that possible, ccording to the Array#includes definition in the [ECMAScript 2016 (ECMA-262) docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes):

> The includes method intentionally differs from the similar indexOf
>   method in two ways. First, it uses the SameValueZero algorithm,
>   instead of Strict Equality Comparison, allowing it to detect **NaN**
>   array elements. Second, it does not skip missing array elements,
>   instead treating them as undefined.

The definition of [SameValueZero(x, y)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) states that when comparing:

> If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function.

Answer (score 0):

`[ NaN ].includes(NaN)` what this does is to check if `NaN` is in the `[ ]`.

`NaN === NaN` and `NaN == NaN` will still return the same value which is `false`. What you just have to know is that the `includes` methods checks if a value is the array it is been called on. Behind the hood i think the `includes` Array method does it's checks using `typeof()`

```
typeof(NaN) // number
[ NaN ].includes(NaN) // true

typeof("1") // string
[ 1 ].includes("1") // false

typeof(1) // number
[ 1 ].includes(1) // true
```

this is according to the [SameValueZero](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) Algorithm that the `includes` method uses. Internally it checks the type of the value